# Windows XP: Allow software settings modification for limited user accounts

Tags: windows-xp, limited-user-account

How can a limited user account change software settings that are on allowed to administerators

for eg: my sister logs into my computer and wants to apply a firewall rule permanently (eset smart security just in case you are wondering what antivir and firewall) but that is not allowed as she is logging in from a limited account. She is allowed to apply the rule but not permanently this causes a lot of nag screens, is it possible to allow certain software setting modifications like this and avoid having me to login and logout of the admin account just to apply the settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things that Vista and 7, as well as Ubuntu, beat XP in.
As close as you'll get to those OSs' admin functionality is the Right Click->Run As.. context menu item. Kill the program, then navigate to the executable (in Program Files), and then right click and hit the Run as.. item. Type in your username and password.

Another option for the commandline that does the same thing is the [`runas`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command.

Comment: but that still makes me type my username and password doesn't it.. tsk.. tsk..

Comment: Well, if you don't want to type your password, you're going to have to give it to her no matter what. Windows has an all-or-nothing privilege system.